# how to enable script debugging in visual studio 2008 when using Firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm using Firefox as my default browser and I'm trying to debug java script  in side asp.net page  visual studio 2008 with Firefox browser.

how to enable script debugging in visual studio 2008 when using Firefox?

by the way, I installed JavaScript Debugger plug-in for Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to attach to a non-IE browser in Visual Studio unless someone knows of a trick I don't. You'll want to either use the infinitely useful [Firebug Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) for Firefox or the more feature rich [Venkman debugger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216/).

I have had issues with scripts being cached in FF while you're developing, so I would suggest making frequent use of the [CTRL][SHIFT] + Delete shortcut to clear your cache.  Another trick I use is to insert

```
debugger;
```

into your script where you want to make sure you break into the debugger.  I'm sure this works in Firebug and may also in Venkman.

Happy debugging.

Comment: Another way of completely refreshing the page would be CTRL+F5, which will set no-cache headers to the refresh request.